# Setting state mismatch in ReactJS with GraphQL

Tags: reactjs, graphql

I am currently trying to implement a infinite scroll with React and GraphQL. In my **detectScroll** function, I am trying to detect the last shown element on screen and make a fetch request based on its attribute.

However, the issue that I'm having is that my **data list doesn't contain the full amount of elements shown on the screen.**

The data is initially loaded into the page via a GraphQL hook. The hook itself is not in a useEffect function or anything:

```
  const { results } = fetchNewUserData(period,lastTime);
  const [local, setLocal] = useState(results);

  const detectScroll = () => {
    if (myRef.current) {
      const { scrollHeight, scrollTop, clientHeight } = myRef.current!;
      const isNear = scrollTop + clientHeight >= scrollHeight - clientHeight;

        if (isNear && local){
          const last = local?.length - 1;
           // ---> Issue is here. the state of local doesn't contain the newly fetched array items. <------
          setLastTime(local[last].creationTime);  
        }
    }
  }

 const scrollDebounce = useCallback(debounce(detectScroll , 100), [local]);

  useEffect(() => {
    myRef.current?.addEventListener('scroll', scrollDebounce , true);

    return () => {
      myRef.current?.removeEventListener('scroll', scrollDebounce , true);
    };
  }, []);
```

In this useEffect hook, I listen for changes to the **lastTime** value and use **setLocal** to update my data.

```
  useEffect(() => {
    if (results) {
      const elements = removeDuplicates([...localData as any, ...results as any], 'id');
      setLocal(elements);
    }
  }, [period, results , local, lastTime]);
```